# Add custom icon into webview already loaded website

Tags: android, webview

How i can add custom icon in webview like this app doing https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAQaC.jpg

I want to add custom icon like below app and this app how should work guys can you please help

Comment: this is download icon, add image in drawable folder , then use imageview , set gravity center

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't have code i want develop like same as they are implement inner side of webview